# WSO2 Identity Server - Adding Service Provider using SQL

Tags: sql, wso2, service-provider, wso2-identity-server

WSO2 Identity Server 5.0.0

I am wondering what the full path of SQL queries would be if i wanted to create and update Service providers via SQL queries.  It's more than adding to the SP_APP table as a newly inserted entry by that means doesn't show in the UI.  I was looking through the identity-core code and got a little lost, since it seems to abstract out some intricate registry stuff.

Anyway, I'd love to know how I could navigate the database to look at stuff by these means.

Comment: Why you need to create SPs directly in the database. If you need to don't need to use the management console to create the service providers, you can use the admin service.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest moving your WSO2 IS completely onto SQL Server. You can then see all the tables and scripts that are run against it (using something like QueryProfiler). To do this, follow the instructions: https://docs.wso2.com/display/ML111/Setting+up+Microsoft+SQL.
Note that at the end of the document you must run two scripts (not just the one they show):

1. `<PRODUCT_HOME>/dbscripts/mssql.sql`
2. `<PRODUCT_HOME>/dbscripts/identity/mssql.sql`

I have to admit that the documentation on WSO2 IS is not very good or complete, but they have been good at answering questions. SQL Server was hard to set up as some of the steps were old (as you see they reference SQL Server 2005), but if you know your way around SQL Server pretty well, you can figure out the minor things. The largest issue was the second .sql script that needed to be run.
That should set you up well enough to see what is being called when set up Service Providers, or anything else that goes into the database.